# Making a choice between two homescreens

Tags: android, homepage

I need to make a choice between two home screens for my Android app.

The user of this app will take a Business Card or an image of a Business card, scan it using OCR and upon obtaining a satisfactory result, save it to his contacts. OCR on a bad image can be a painful experience, though - he may save one contact every 5 or 6 scans - so I went with the most frequently contacted people which seemed reasonable for a business app.

One of them is spartan in look and feel and only consists of the functionality I added to the app:

[image: Simple and Spartan]

The other lists the top 10 frequently called contacts without enhancing the functionality of the app. As alternate possibilities, I can make it a contacts app by itself, and the action buttons can be moved to the top.

[image: consists of the top 10 contacts]

Comment: What's the purpose of this application? What is important and what will users be doing most? Consider that if it is just for taking and viewing pictures, for instance, a contact list would be entirely irrelevant - but it would be very different if this is a chat application, or made for sharing photos with others.

Comment: The user will take a Business Card or an image of a Business card,scan it using OCR and upon obtaining a satisfactory result,save it to his contacts but OCR on a bad image can be a painful experience...he may save one contact every 5 or 6 scans...so I went with the most frequently contacted people which seemed reasonable for a business app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the second screen where I have access to recent contacts. I'd go with recent scans though.

For most frequently contacted, I'll go to the Contacts instead of the app. There'll be moments when I've just scanned the contact and would want view it again, instead of looking for the contact again, as I may not even remember the name correctly.

I'd suggest to also provide a textbox for quick search of scanned contact.

If it's not too complicated, consider showing a part of the scanned business card together with the contact information. You rarely take a picture of the guy gave you the card, but it's really easy to remember that guy from the logo on the card, so seeing the logo (most of the time top left corner) is more useful than contact picture for the user.

Comment: So,I show recently scanned contacts...should I do it from the first scanned contact or wait till there are say 5 or more.And do I show 10 which would fill the screen or just 5 to keep it minimal?

Comment: @user2309862 You should try some user testing and work it out. Generally, please avoid asking follow-up questions on answers covering things not covered by your original question.